# How do I get the current length of the input inside of creatableselect?

Tags: reactjs

```
<CreatableSelect
   value={goal}
   options={goalOptions}
   onChange={(e) =>  {setGoal(e)}}
   placeholder="Select... or type your own!"/>
<div>{goal.length}</div>
```

this only gives the length of the goal after the user presses enter, but is there a way to constantly update the length as the user writes?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `goal` and `setGoal` as state.

example:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const MyFunctionalComponent = () => {

    const [goal, setGoal] = React.useState('')

    return (<>
              <CreatableSelect value = {goal}
                options = {goalOptions}
                onChange = {(e) => {setGoal(e)}}
                placeholder = "Select... or type your own!" 
               />
               <div>{goal.length}</div> 
            </>)
};
```